# Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't let me to uninstall applications

Tags: 16.04, software-uninstall

I like to have only what I need on my computer and hence I always follow the practice of removing the programs I know I'm not going to use.

I just downloaded Ubuntu 16.04 LTS but I'm unable to uninstall applications. I go to the Software Center and hit remove for the apps I want to (Mozilla, Mahjong, Solitaire, etc). Everything seems to work. However, after twenty seconds the Software Center refreshes itself and the apps are back!!
Please, help! It's really annoying.

Is there any way to remove these apps from the Terminal?

Comment: It is installed alongside windows 10, in it's own partition on my only HDD

Comment: If you have found a solution to your problem in any of the answers, do not forget to select it so this thread closes.

Answer (score 6):

I ran into a similar problem. I would click the "Remove" button in the software center, but the applications would re-appear after a short period. I did this for the Aisle Riot Solitaire program, for example, and it kept coming back. When I went to remove it with the command line, however, it said it was not installed:

```
$ sudo apt-get purge aisleriot
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'aisleriot' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 87 not upgraded.
```

After more investigation (read: blind clicking), I discovered that clicking the refresh icon on the Updates tab actually seemed to refresh the Installed tab as well (even though the refresh icon is not available on the Installed tab). After this, Solitaire stopped showing up.

[image: Screen shot of Ubuntu Software showing refresh icon in upper left corner.]

*By "refresh icon", I mean the circular arrow in the upper left corner.*

Comment: @DavidForester thanks for edit - I didn't have enough rep to inline the image.

Answer (score 4):

If you are comfortable with the command line, the way to remove a software is:

```
sudo apt-get remove software_name
```

or

```
sudo apt-get purge software_name
```

The latter removes configuration files as well.  Since you no longer seem to be interested in the software, you should probably use `purge`.

You will, however, need to find the name for each of the packages you are trying to uninstall/remove from your system. The ones you mentioned in your post would be `firefox` (assuming that is what you meant with Mozilla),  `gnome-mahjongg`, `aisleriot`.  Therefore, to remove those three you would do this:

```
sudo apt-get purge firefox gnome-mahjongg aisleriot
```

To find the name of the package is sometimes tricky (for instance it took me some time to find the name for `aisleriot`).  You can install `synaptic` and that will help you find the name more easily.  Mind you though, you may need to uninstall synaptic afterwards as you seem to be concerned about software you will not be using.

You may find this post useful as well: [install/remove list of packages from command line with apt-get](https://askubuntu.com/questions/293030/install-remove-list-of-packages-from-command-line-with-apt-get)  as it shows how you can remove software that is in a list.

Also, this very recent post talks about removing the gemes: [How can I remove all default installed games?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32228/how-can-i-remove-all-default-installed-games)

**Note**: I would not recommend to remove firefox to have a backup browser in case Chromium or whatever other browser does not work.

Comment: This is great! Thanks for the help. Is there something wrong with the software centre? Is this a bug? If so, how can I report it to Canonical?

Comment: @VihanAgarwal See http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug

Answer (score 0):

Direct answer:
removing packages using terminal/cli/tty:

```
# apt-get remove SoftwareName
```

common example:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove firefox
```

The above would result in something like:

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  firefox
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 9 not upgraded.
After this operation, 110 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

Entering 'Y' would then remove firefox.

You can also use purge,

```
$ sudo apt-get remove --purge somePackage
$ sudo apt-get purge somePackage
```

the 2 commands above are equivalent. (see man apt-get).

'purge' removes the selected package and its configuration file(s)

Less certain/more general:
From your description of using the Software Center, it sounds like you are using Ubuntu directly from the live image; meaning it seems like Ubuntu is not installed to a drive. I don't have personal experience with using the Software Center, so I could be wrong about this point.

Re

> I like to have only what I need on my computer and hence I always follow the practice of removing the programs I know I'm not going to use.

That's fine, but be careful about assumptions based on other operating systems. If you find you enjoy Linux you may consider reversing that, and *installing* only what you need -building your system from the ground up.

Answer (score 0):

Run:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

to attempt to fix the problem.